# I put that someone could claim me as a dependent on accident but no one will/did claim me as one

Tags: united-states, income-tax, dependents, covid-19, stimulus

I did my taxes on turbo tax and didn’t realize that I put that someone could claim me. No one actually claimed me. Will I still qualify for a stimulus check?

Comment: "No one actually claimed you" does not mean that no one **could** claim you. The question that is asked of you on your tax return is whether someone **could** claim you (i.e. whether someone meets the conditions in the law to claim you). You are required to answer Yes if someone **could** claim you, even if nobody actually does. So, does someone meet the conditions in the law to claim you?

Comment: No, they don’t. Thank you for your answer!

Answer (score 3):

Probably not.  I would suggest filing an amended return.  You might also get a bigger refund, because you would be able to take the normal standard deduction.